# How to change MySQL date format to string date

Tags: mysql

> 2012-02-14?

How can I modify the above MYSQL statement to format the date into string date format i.e.

> 2012-FEB-02?

Comment: `02` in the original date was the month, yet you want `FEB-02` (i.e. month appearing twice, in different forms) in your output?

Answer (score 4):

Use MySQL's [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2012-02-14', '%Y-%b-%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL [DateFormat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

DATE_FORMAT(<your_date_field>, '%Y-%b-%d')

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MySQLs [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), it gives you alot of possibilities to format a given date to your needs.

Example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2012-02-14', "%Y-%b-%m");
```

Result:

```
2012-Feb-02
```

... and if you really want the month abbreviation in capital letters (aka `FEB` instead of `Feb`, like your example result), simply wrap an [`UPPER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) around it:

```
SELECT UPPER(DATE_FORMAT('2012-02-14', "%Y-%b-%m"));
```

Result:

```
2012-FEB-02
```